# Bash operator < , > , | and grep / kill

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill

As an exercise, I wanted to kill a process by command line using basic bash principles but i'm having some errors that i don't understand:

```
ps -A | grep nautilus | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,5}' | kill
```

1) It doesn't work

If i try

```
ps -A | grep nautilus | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,5}' > kill
```

2) Doesn't work either

3) If i do  `(..) egrep '\d' (...)` shouldn't this be the same as [0-9] ?

4) Is there any way that i do something like this:

```
kill < (greps (...) )
```

Comment: Why is this getting migrated? Isn't it programming related?

Comment: It is absurd that this was migrated. Shell scripting is absolutely programming related.

Comment: First of all: `nautilus -q` (!!); otherwise `killall name`, `pgrep -fl name`, `pkill -f name`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
kill `ps -A | grep nautilus | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,5}'`
```

The commands within the backticks will be executed and fed as a part of the command.

Comment: ... or using `$()` instead of the backticks, easier to read :)

Comment: The assumption of 4-5 digits is strange; most ps implementations don't zero-pad the left of pids, and pid usage can wrap around.  Some OSes even actually use more than 16-bits of pid space.

Answer (score 3):

1. The `|` operator feeds the "standard output" (stdout) from the left to the "standard input" of the right; standard input, or stdin, is equivalent to "what I read as though from the user if they type into me".  The `kill(1)` command kills the process ids provided on its command-line, not on its stdin.  So inserting `xargs` before `kill` would help:

   ```
   ... | xargs kill
   ```

   because `xargs(1)` takes its stdin and batches it up into chunks, to repeatedly invoke the supplied command (here, "kill") with command-lines made up of those chunks.
2. The `>` operator is used to redirect stdout to a file, so you've created a new file in the current directory, which has the filename "kill" and contents of the pids.
3. The pattern `\d` is not a part of either the "standard" or "extended" regular expression languages; instead, it was introduced by Perl (I believe) and is in many later variants of the regular expression language.  PCRE, for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, provides a library which was instrumental in spreading the extended syntax to many other tools and languages, but is certainly not the only implementation today.  There are websites which will provide matrix comparisons of the different regexp languages for you.

   PCRE ships with `pcregrep(1)` which will understand `\d` for you; also, modern GNU grep has the `-P` option, which will use PCRE for regexps.
4. You're here after the concept called "command substitution", where the stdout of the command is used directly in the command-line; the modern syntax for this is `$(...)`, although you'll also see backticks used, `...` but that's historical and doesn't nest well.  So:

   ```
   kill $(ps ... | pcregrep ... | munge)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the executable, it is better to use `pidof`to find the pid of the running program.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `killall`:

```
killall nautilus
```

(from the package `psmisc`, at least in debian/ubuntu).

Comment: OP didn't state their OS.  Better hope it's not SysV, such as Solaris, in which `killall` doesn't do what you think it does. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most Linuxes have [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) (and `pgrep`) which do what you want.

```
pkill nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `xargs`:

```
ps -A | grep nautilus | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,5}' | xargs -L 1 kill
```

Actually, `kill` accepts multiple arguments, so `-L 1` is not strictly needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
   ps -A | grep nautilus | awk '{print "kill " $1}' | bash
```

I would do it this way, but there are many ways to execute the same thing =)
I had this answer written out in detail on stackoverflow, to find it migrated here.

Comment: why? curious. in particular about the last part 'awk '{print "kill " $1}' | bash'